# AIR application not finding locale properties file

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, properties, air

I have the problem that when I use a component from an existing Flex Library in my AIR project, the values that should be loaded from the appropriate locale .properties file are not loaded. The values are always null.

I am using Eclipse and have created an AIR project that refers to the existing Flex Library (of which I have the source code). When I use a component from that library it calls the following code:

```
var _resourceManager:IResourceManager = ResourceManager.getInstance();
var res:String = resourceManager.getString('resources', str, params);
```

"str" and "params" have valid values but res is always null.

The properties file is located within the assets directory of the Flex library. I am deducing that the properties file is not being loaded (for some reason). This Flex library works for other Flex projects so it has to be something about the way my project is set up.

I have my compiler settings set to: -locale en_US

Is there something special that AIR projects need to do to ensure that they can refer to properties files?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Upon further investigation I don't believe this is an AIR issue. I created a new Flex Project (not AIR) with an MXML Application and this couldn't obtain the properties file either. I think the issue is how does a project ensure that the properties file is loaded for a dependant library?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a compiler issue. It seems you have not set the locale folder in the compiler arguments.

Take a look at the LiveDocs page concerning resource compilation into Flex applications: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/l10n_3.html#158879

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. I already have -locale en_US in both the Flex library and the Flex application project.